# How can I add a custom Kotlin postfix completion in IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

It seems I can't add custom postfix completions for Kotlin in neither IntelliJ IDEA (2018.3), nor in Android studio (3.2.1). If I go to preferences | Editor | General | Postfix Completion and I click the add button, there is no option for Kotlin (see screenshots below). Is it possible to add new postfix completions?

I'd like to add a `.with` postfix completion, so that `x.with` would expand to

```
with(x) {
    // The caret should go here
}
```

Side note: I think it's a shame there is no postfix completion for `with` out of the box.

Screenshots of IntelliJ IDEA (2018.3) and Android Studio (3.2.1):

[image: IntelliJ IDEA postfix completion settings]
[image: Android Studio postfix completion settings]

Comment: See the Kotlin IntelliJ plugin issue on YouTrack: [Support custom postfix completion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-16206/Support-custom-postfix-completion).

Answer (score 6):

I checked, and it's not possible in Android Studio nor IntelliJ. Probably the definition language doesn't have support for Kotlin yet.

However, what you could try, is try the following plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9862-custom-postfix-templates.

It seems to be well maintained, and has support for Scala, Kotlin, Groovy, etc. I haven't tried it myself, but based on the documentation, it seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: That plugin doesn't have any Kotlin postfix completions by default, but I've made my own. It's not trivial to add and edit your own postfix additions, it's quite an involved plugin.

Comment: I appreciate the added information, but can you please not edit my answer? I have reverted your changes.